# kdb - how generate HEX colour code as string or symbol

Tags: kdb

I would like to create a column on an in-memory table that generates a colour HEX code based on a person's name (another column). A quick google didn't give much so wondered if any pointers can be given here.
e.g

```
update colour: <some code and use username col as input> from table
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In kdb+ you can run a function on a column via an `update` statement but there are slight differences depending on whether the function is vectorised or not. If vectorised:

```
update colour:{<some code>}[username] from table
update colour:someFunction[username] from table
```

If not vectorised then an iterator like [each `'`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/#quote) is required

```
update colour:{<some code>}'[username] from table
update colour:someFunction'[username] from table
```

This function will generate hex codes from the first 3 characters of a string.

```
q)hex:{a:i-16*j:(i:`int$3#x)div 16;"0123456789ABCDEF"raze(j-16*j div 16),'a}
q)hex"Hello"
"48656C"
q)update colour:hex'[username] from table
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my question was not about how to update a column (vectorised or using each). It was about if there's a clever way to generate a hex code

Comment: In that regard you question is quite vague. What attempts have you made to generate HEX codes so far? Under what rules should the conversion be made? Do you only need the first 3 characters of a string to do it? I've added a hex code generator function to my answer.